# Javascript Failing to Correctly Compare Two Strings

Tags: javascript, string, compare

I first create a list of characters, and save two of them as strings which are dependent on user input. I am unsure as to where the issue lies so I copied the full code is here https://jsfiddle.net/mboguslaw97/6w6xj1f3/3/. The top left card and the one 2 below that are both 'L's. Click another card after those to activate the alert statements.

```
var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'.repeat(2).split('');
user_input = 11;
cards_flipped.push(user_input);
user_input = 23;
cards_flipped.push(user_input);
letter1 = letters[cards_flipped[0]];
letter2 = letters[cards_flipped[1]];

alert(letter1 == 'L');
alert(letter2 == 'L');
alert(letter1 == letter2)
//Alerts true, true, false
```

Could somebody please explain to me how to detect if the strings are equal and why the strings cannot be compare this way?

Comment: What is `.repeat()` ? What is expected result ?

Comment: looks like fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/wqpLzffk/

Comment: Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/mboguslaw97/6w6xj1f3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(typeof letter1, letter1 instanceof Array);
object true
```

letter1 and letter2 are both single value arrays. The only reason that either of them "equals" the letter 'L' is because of type conversion: the [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method is being called on the array when comparing to a string literal. If you compare `letter1.toString() == letter2.toString()` or `letter1[0] == letter2[0]`, they will be equal. I updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w6xj1f3/4/).

Cheers.